# Encountering login issues after implementing the feature to create custom tokens using Firebase Admin

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

After adding Firebase Admin to create custom tokens in the backend, the login functionality is being disrupted. I have already checked the console, and the service credential file appears to be logging in properly without any issues.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { error } = require("console");

const serviceAccount = require(process.env.FIREBASE_GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);


// const firebase_app = initializeApp();
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

app.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await loginUser(username, password);
        const { id, role } = user; // Assuming the user object contains a "role" property
        // const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(user.id);
        if (!user.user_id || typeof user.user_id !== 'string') {
            throw new Error('Invalid user ID');
        }
        console.log(user.user_id);
        const uid = uuidv4();
        console.log(uid);
        admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid).then((customToken) => {
                return customToken
                console.log(customToken);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error creating custom token', error)
            })
     res.json({ token: customToken, user });
        // Include the "role" property in the response
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});
```

There is no problem with loginUser function ,it is working fine. without createcustomtoken function my code runs fine

Below is my frontend code,in case you need for further analysis.

```
export const handleLogin = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/login`, {
      username,
      password,
    });

    console.log("Login successful", response);
    
    // const { user, role } = response.data; // Extract the user and role from the response data
    //  const user = response.data;
  //  const token = response.headers.authorization;
  //   console.log("Token:", token);
 const token = response.data.token;
    console.log("Token:", token);
    console.log(response.data);
    const { id, role } = response.data;

    // Perform actions based on the user role
console.log("id:",response.data.id)
    if (response.data.role === "admin") {
      window.location.href = `${baseUrl}/`; // Redirect to admin page for admin users
    } else {
      console.log("normal user" );
    }

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Login failed", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Note: i am not using firebase db to store the data and checking from it if user exists.

Comment: "the login functionality is being disrupted" is hard to help with. What doesn't work about the code you shared? Is there an error message? If not, If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: thanks , it is fixed .not working because of this
if (!user.user_id || typeof user.user_id !== 'string') {
            throw new Error('Invalid user ID');
        }